# AspxGridView Change Datatable Column Value for Current Page

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

**Problem :** DataTable (50K+ Rows) is binded with Aspxgridview, now we want to change DataRow column Values... for example instead of UserId display UserName.
I can enumerate 50K rows and update userid with username at runtime but i want to enumerate AspxGridView current page DataRows and update their values only.

Can anyone guide me ? which event to use to update dataRow values of current page only for Aspxgridview ?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT iterate through the 50K records an update the UserId with the UserName.

One, you probably cant because UserId sounds like a numeric field (or at least it should be) and UserName is a string field. You can't put a string in a number.

Two, You should change the way you get your data, likely from a database, to JOIN the table you have here to the table that has the user names, and bring in the data you want.  This way, it is done, and done fast.

Comment: I can understand...but In this case there is no other option other then to pragmatically add another column to Data table and assign Employee-Name...

Comment: On each postback, you need to figure out what page you are on and how many records are in each page, then fill those in, if they are not already.  You can do this on the Page_Load event or in the event fired by the DataGrid_PageChanging event or what ever you're using for you paging.

Comment: BTW, I do most of my work with DevExpress ASP Grid in the `ASPxGridView_DataBinding` event. Gets called just before it needs to load the data in the grid.